# Run nvm (bash function) via sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, bash-script, function

I want to write a init script that should basically run

```
nvm use v0.11.12 && forever start /srv/index.js
```

as the user `webconfig`. `nvm` is a shell function that is declared in `~webconfig/.nvm/nvm.sh`, which is included via `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` in `webconfig`'s `.bashrc`.

I tried the following:

```
sudo -H -i -u webconfig nvm

echo "nvm" | sudo -H -i -u webconfig
```

but they fail with

> -bash: nvm: command not found
>   -bash: line 1: nvm: command not found

When I run `sudo -H -i -u webconfig` and enter `nvm` manually in that shell, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is this function defined?

Comment: In `~webconfig/.bashrc`, there is a line `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`. The function is defined in `~webconfig/.nvm/nvm.sh`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include those details. The answer depends on exactly where and how the files are sourced.

Comment: @terdon Did id, although I hoped there was a solution that does not hard-code the path. But it will be ok either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here, as is so often the case, is about the different types of shell:

- When you open a terminal emulator (`gnome-terminal` for example), you are executing what is known as an *interactive, non-login* shell.
- When you log into your machine from the command line, or run a command such as `su username`, or `sudo -u username`, you are running an *interactive login* shell.

So, depending on what type of shell you have started, a different set of startup files are read. From `man bash`:

```
   When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-inter‐
   active shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes  com‐
   mands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading
   that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile,
   in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that
   exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be  used  when  the
   shell is started to inhibit this behavior.
```

In other words, `~/.bashrc` is ignored by login shells. Since you are using the `-i` option to `sudo`, the startup files for the user's login shell are being read (from `man sudo`):

```
 -i, --login
             Run the shell specified by the target user's password data‐
             base entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific
             resource files such as .profile or .login will be read by the
             shell.
```

So, what you can do is

1. Define the function in the user's `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` instead. Bear in mind that `~/.profile` is ignored if `~/.bash_profile` exists. Also keep in mind that `~/.bash_profile` is bash-specific so I would use `.profile` instead, just make sure that `~/.bash_profile` does not exist.
2. Source `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` from `~/.profile`.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works when they do `sudo -H -i -u webconfig` and run `nvm` manually. My suspicion is that there already is some code to source `.bashrc` from `.profile`, but for some reason it only works in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! I took the second approach, but kept it also in `~/.bashrc` beause otherwise it doesn't work with `su webconfig`. @Graeme No, `.profile` and `.bash_profile` did not exist at all. I tried [including `.bashrc` in `.profile`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment/415444#415444), but it did not work.

Comment: @Graeme that's probably because when run manually it is being run by the OP's normal user and some of his environment is being kept. When run from the init files, it is run by `root` so the situation is different. Not sure how, mind you.

Comment: @terdon: I don't have a "normal user" (it's a development machine), so only `webconfig` and root were involved. I ran the test lines in the question as root.

Answer (score 4):

[@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125793/48083) has already added some good detail on this, so I won't repeat that here. To restate, the cause of the issue is most likely down to the somewhat odd behaviour that `bash` has when invoked as a login shell in that it doesn't automatically source the `.bashrc` and instead looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` only.

It is common practice to add code to one of these profile files to source the `.bashrc`. By default I have the following code in `~/.profile`:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi
```

#### Update

From the comments below, I think the best solution is probably to remove the `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` line from the `.bashrc` and leave everything else as is.

Comment: Thanks! I now spotted why this did not work in the first place: `.bashrc`'s first line is `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` (Ubuntu 12.04). If I remove that line, this solution works. I wonder if it's a good idea...

Comment: @Yogu that comes down to personal preference but that is the default on many distros now. Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/432508/85695) for the rationale.

Comment: @Yogu, `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` would make the `.bashrc` exit it it is non-interactive. I think this has probably been the source of the issue and that there has been some code elsewhere that sources the `.bashrc`. This would explain why the function only works when the shell is run interactively.

Comment: I found an [explanation why it's that way](http://askubuntu.com/questions/352866/why-default-bashrc-is-set-to-return-immediately-if-not-running-interactively), so to be safe I better not remove that line.

Comment: @Yogu, I don't think that it makes much difference. Usually when you run a script, nothing gets sourced. By adding options for a login or interactive shell, you are basically saying you want things to be sourced. That said, `bash` does allow for separation between login and interactive which may be useful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo -Hu webconfig bash -c '. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm'
```

Comment: Yeah, that would probably work, but I don't like having this hard-coded dependency. I might want to move `nvm.sh` at some time.