# Run .bashrc function as sudo

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo, function

I added this to `~/.bashrc` to provide colorized tail:

```
tailc () {
  tail $@ | ccze
}
```

And I can run it as so: `tailc -f -n 10 foo/log.txt`

But I can't use it on a privileged file:

```
sudo tailc -f -n 10 /var/log/syslog
```

Error:

> bash: tailc: command not found

I know I can do it like this: `sudo bash -i -c '...'` but I want to know if I can run it without that more complicated syntax. **What can I do to be able to just type `sudo tailc ...`?**

BTW, I added that function to `/root/.bashrc` as well, but that didn't help either.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125812/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101620/how-to-load-bashrc-from-bash-c

Comment: ...and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472212/364705 for a lengthy explanation from the sidebar

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @markgraf "the sidebar"??

Comment: @lonix One of the links under "Related"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is:

```
sudo bash -i -c 'tailc -f -n 10 /var/log/syslog'
```

But that syntax is ugly, so I went in a different direction.

I created a script `/usr/local/bin/tailc` with permission 755:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

tail $@ | ccze
```

Now I can use `tailc` / `sudo tailc` as I wanted.